# How to acess parents component variable in child component

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a variable from a parent component in child components and set it via method of another variable.

However, I am unable to use it. Please can anyone guide me on how to implement it.

Parent Component

```js
@Component({
  ...,
  template: `<child [var1]="var1" [var2]="var2"><child>`
})
export class ParentComponent implements onInit {

  var1: any;
  var2: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.subscribe(data => {
      this.var1.push(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Child Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  ...
})
export class childComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() var1:any;

  private var2Value: any;
  @Input() get var2(): any {
    return this.var2Value;
  }
  set var2(val){
    console.log(var1); //  it shows undefined in the console.
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(var1);
  }
}
```

When I use it in the set method of another variable in child component it shows undefined in console. But, when i use it in ngOnInit method in child component it shows the data in console.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here.. do you even use a proper code editor? I can see at least 5 errors without further looking, so please put your code inside a proper code editor, get rid of all the errors and check again. With that being said, i dont see the effort here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to start by typify your components. Typescript exists because we think typification assists in development. You should apply it here such that you get the following:

In the parent component:

```js
  var1: any[];
  var2: any[];
```

In the child component:

```js
@Input() var1: any[];
```

Next there is an error in your code concerning the the `var1` of the parent component is not being initialized. Because of this, you cannot push on to it. Therefore I would update has:

```js
  var1: any[] = [];
  var2: any[];
```

Following this, I would be check your `dataService`.

Unless your service extends from `Subscription` or similar, you cannot call subscribe directly on it so I would check if you are calling the correct property because the below seems odd:

```js
    this.dataService.subscribe(data => {
      ...
    });
```

Lastly, I would check what is the type of `Subject` that is being this observable (`dataService.subscrive`). I tried your code with a `setInterval` and I manage to get the values in both.

I would also advise that the following are not equal:

1. `<child [var2]="var2" [var1]="var1"></child>`
2. `<child [var1]="var1" [var2]="var2"></child>`

The 1º passes the value to `var2` before `var1` is set. The 2º passes the value to `var2` after `var1` is set. This is because Angular passes the inputs according to the order provided in the HTML.
So if you write the html like in the first case, `var1` will be undefined in the `set` of `var2` but be defined in the `ngOnInit()`.